# Vue Production issue with Express

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to install SSR on my current Vue app, and for this I'm using the `vue-plugin-ssr` extension. I want to run it with express, so I created a new file called server.mjs and have this:

```
import express from "express";
import { createServer as createViteServer } from "vite";
import { renderPage } from "vite-plugin-ssr";

async function createServer() {
  const app = express();

  // Create Vite server in middleware mode and configure the app type as
  // 'custom', disabling Vite's own HTML serving logic so parent server
  // can take control
  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: "custom",
  });

  // use vite's connect instance as middleware
  // if you use your own express router (express.Router()), you should use router.use
  app.use(vite.middlewares);

  app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
    // `renderPage()` can also be used in serverless environments such as
    // Cloudflare Workers and Vercel
    const { httpResponse } = await renderPage({ url: req.url });
    res.send(httpResponse.body);
  });

  app.listen(3000);
}

createServer();
```

So this actually works for dev, when I run `node server.mjs`, but neither client or server folder has an index.html file, so how can I run this on production actually?
Only what I'm doing is to set the folder on nginx to path/dist/client, do I need to do something else?

btw as a response on production I have only 403 forbbiden.

Comment: You say "vue" but your import uses "vite". Intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the client and ssr build process [as demonstrated in Vite's documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#building-for-production) and then:

> Move the creation and all usage of the `vite` dev server behind dev-only
> conditional branches, then add static file serving middlewares to
> serve files from `dist/client`

Comment: I actually have some progress, but not good for production. Can you checkout the console of https://staging.gamespace.gg/ ?